# Cannot assign sharing rule to guest User for custom object

Tags: community, standard-objects, guest-user

I want to give access to my Community guest user for my objects , but I don't see the setting available for my Custom Object.

for reference : -

Standard Object(product):-

[image]

Custom object(Business Brand):-

[image: cannot select Guest User access]

What am I missing for Custom object ??

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_guest_sharing_criteria.htm&type=5 Does this answer your question?

Comment: no , couldn't find Service Resource Sharing Rules settings

Answer (score 0):

I was able to grant read access to my guest users by giving a very wide criteria.
In this case: id<>0 fetches all records. The system then allows me to pick guest user.
[image: Example]